# Information on VBA Chart Exporting

Tags: excel, vba

I usually export Excel charts with code like:

```
Sub SaveChart()
    Dim ch As Chart
    Set ch = ActiveChart
    ch.Export Filename:="C:\TestFolder\tempxx.jpg", FilterName:="JPG"
End Sub
```

I would like to explore using other picture formats.  I would like to know what are the valid values for **FilterName.**  However *VBA Help* has nothing useful.  Can anyone point me an online resource that gives this information??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF and PNG are the commonly used picture format which should work With Chart.Export. FilterName is The language-independent name of the graphic filter as it appears in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Graphics Filters.

Comment: PNG should most likely be used. Gif isn't too bad. JPG can result in a graphic with strange artifacts, because JPG format was designed for photographic images, not for line art. All of these will work. I've had mixed results with BMP, TIFF and others, but as stated, PNG is best.

Answer (score 0):

For many years (beginning with Excel 2003) I used GIF but at some stage Excel became incapable of exporting my charts properly, giving the saved chart a black background that rendered in grey in some applications. Switching to PNG has restored the functionality

Comment: can you reference any online resource as per the OPs question?